# Memory limit issue on Magento 2.2 EE

Tags: magento2, php, memory

I have installed an instance of Magento Commerce 2.2 on a server with Digital Ocean ensuring stack requirements are met and have been experiencing regular PHP Fatal Error Out of Memory Issues, and when checking the server stats it would seem that the CPU and memory usages are continuously reaching 100% usage.

All caching options are enabled, and we have around 10 people working on data input in the admin at the moment.

Would you be able to enlighten me as to what could be causing this?

I was considering upgrading hardware with my hosting provider but am worried that it will max resources out again if this is some kind of a memory leak...

Here are my specs:

4 GB Memory

60 GB Disk

Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64

Apache/2.4.28

MysQL Distrib 5.7.19

php 7.1

Magento 2.2 EE

I changed the memory_limit to 1024M

Some of the errors I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 8388608) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /path-to-magento/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php on line 37

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 8388608) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /path-to-magento/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php on line 227

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 8388608) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /path-to-magento/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php on line 227

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /path-to-magento/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
```

Here is what the usage is looking like on my dashboard:

[Server resource Usage Dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuX8g.png)

Thanks!

Comment: change screenshot to Memory tab in Top processes

Comment: this php memory limit, and if you run long/big data imports it will take upto 2G sometimes

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the memory tab https://imgur.com/HAqmkeS

Comment: We have some people using the backend but I wouldn't think that would cause such a big memory/CPU usage

Comment: it will cause, you have `php-fpm` too low and `php` too high , it means `php` for cron or long running custom scripts, takes all memory and cpu. you need to check it

Comment: @MagenX how would I do to increase the allocated memory for php-fpm?

Comment: php memory limit is global.

Comment: I am having the same issue. It looks like generated/metadata/global.php might be the culprit. Still looking into it

Comment: I'm not running any custom scripts, this is an out of the box install I am using for testing purposes.